# OpenCV installation in ubuntu 18.04 on Jetson Nano

Tags: command-line, 18.04, apt, updates, opencv

when I am running this ubuntu command below error is coming:

For installation I am using this link:
https://jkjung-avt.github.io/opencv-on-nano/

```
Err:12 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release                                                                                                                                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.248 80]
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                                              
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Comment: If you're on 18.04, why do your sources say 16.04?   FYI:   Xenial isn't found in old-releases because of ESM.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Can you please elaborate what i can do for ESM

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has ended it's *standard* support yes, but it's repositories have not moved (*arm64* packages for grub+shim hadn't completed move to 'main' last I heard..  when the move has completed it'll trigger....) however 16.04 is now off-topic on this site and your paste shows *xenial* but you've tagged *bionic* so your question is unclear & currently makes no sense.